# syntax error exception while updating a record in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-update

I am using MySQL database

my PreparedStatement is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@e38b00: UPDATE  tbluser SET (USERID='101',FIRSTNAME='vikram',LASTNAME='sekhar',EMAIL ='r@m') where RECORDID=1

                     pst.executeUpdate();
```

when I try to update the record using `executeUpdate()`
it throws the following syntax error exception. The table in database contains the record with a unique record id RECORDID=1.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(USERID='101',FIRSTNAME='vikram',LASTNAME='sekhar',EMAIL ='r@m') where RECORDID=' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1318)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1303)
    at com.symp.CrudDao.updateUser(CrudDao.java:162)
    at com.symp.CRUDController.service(CRUDController.java:121)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are invalid in an UPDATE statement. Change your statement to :

```
UPDATE  tbluser 
SET     USERID='101',
        FIRSTNAME='vikram',
        LASTNAME='sekhar',
        EMAIL ='r@m' 
WHERE   RECORDID=1
```

Here's the [syntax for UPDATE statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) :

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

As you can see, there are no parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

An `update` statement doesn't have brackets around the field list:

```
UPDATE tbluser 
SET    USERID='101',FIRSTNAME='vikram',LASTNAME='sekhar',EMAIL ='r@m'
WHERE  RECORDID=1
```